# Linq method that Takes and Removes at the same time?

Tags: c#, linq

Is there a linq method that will `Take` and `Remove` at the same time.

Say I want to move the first five elements from one list to another.  I am sure I can do this with several linq statements, but sometimes I find out I have re-invented an already existing method.

Is there such a method now?  (If not I am fine to make it.)

Comment: I find it bizarre that you would actually *want* to mutate a collection with a linq statement.

Comment: There is no Linq statement (method) that Removes at all. Remove is action on a List<>, not on IEnumerable<>.

Comment: You wouldn't want to. It would be equivalent to modifying a collection while enumerating over that collection, and will result in a runtime exception.

Answer (score 4):

No, there isn't. LINQ stands for *Language-Integrated Query*, and all of its methods are for navigating and inspecting existing collections. It doesn't have any methods for mutating collections.

However, you can use some method of the [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cd666k3e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class. Still, there's not single method for this. Here's a minimal solution:

```
list1.AddRange(list2.Take(5));
list2.RemoveRange(0, 5);
```

But if you really wanted to, you could wrap this in a custom extension method:

```
public static class MyListExtensions {
    public static IEnumerable<T> TakeAndRemove<T>(this List<T> list, int count) {
        foreach(var n in list.Take(count))
            yield return n;
        source.RemoveRange(0, count);
    }
}

list1.AddRange(list2.TakeAndRemove(5));
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is no Linq method do it in a single statement. What I have the minimal solution is something like this

```
List<string> one = new List<string>() { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7" };
List<string> two = new List<string>() { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7" };

two.AddRange(one.Take(5));
one.RemoveRange(0, 5);
```

Answer (score 2):

LINQ cannot have a method like that, because it never mutates a collection passed to it. However, you can use LINQ to do most of the work for you.

Consider an example: let's say you need to remove all items that pass a certain condition from `listA`, and add them to `listB`. You can have LINQ partition `listA` into the parts that you wish to keep and the parts that you wish to remove, and then add all removed items to `listB`. Here is how you can do it:

```
// Let's say you want to remove all items with name starting in "X"
// The dictionary will contain two keys - true and false
// Items to keep will be under "true"; items to remove will be under "false"
var d = listA
    .GroupBy(item => !item.Name.StartsWith("X"))
    .ToDictionary(p => p.Key, p => p.ToList());
// Reassign the list of items that you keep to listA
listA = d[true];
// Add items from the list of items to be removed to listB
listB.AddRange(d[false]);
```

Comment: Rather than `GroupBy` followed by `ToDictionary` you can just use `ToLookup`.  It's quicker, easier, and just better all around.

Answer (score 1):

No there is not. You should create your own. I am not sure if that is going to be a good idea doing reading and modifying the list in a same action.

Answer (score 1):

There is no existing LINQ method that does this but it seems like you could build one on top of say `List<T>`.  The basic structure is to have a predicate which removes the values and the function returns the set of values which were removed.

```
static List<T> RemoveAndReturn<T>(this List<T> list, Predicate<T> predicate) {
  var removed = new List<T>();
  int i = 0; 
  while (i < list.Count) {
    var current = list[i];
    if (predicate(current)) { 
      removed.Add(current);
      list.RemoveAt(i);
    } else { 
      i++;
    }
  }

  return removed;
}
```

Note that this isn't truly in the spirit of LINQ though because the first portion executions promptly instead of a delayed fashion.  This is necessary IMHO to avoid accidental double deletes

With this method you could do LINQ like queries that remove and manipulate.  But it would be better to call them fluent instead of LINQ